# Recursive function that shadows a package-level function

Tags: go, recursion, scope

The following outputs "2". Why is that? Should it not recurse and print "210"?

```
    package main

    var f = func(x int) {}

    func Bar() {
        f := func(x int) {
            if x >= 0 {
                println(x)
                f(x - 1)
            }
        }
        f(2)
    }

    func main() {
        Bar()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the global scope, `f` is defined here to take an `int` and do (and return) nothing.

```
    var f = func(x int) {}
```

When you redefine `f` here:

```
        f := func(x int) {
            if x >= 0 {
                println(x)
                f(x - 1)
            }
        }
```

`f` can't be defined until the func is already evaluated, and the "new" `f` func therefore isn't in its own scope.  So `f(x - 1)` still refers to the global func.

Comment: doesn ":=" means define and assign ? still not clear why no recursion takes place at the "f(x - 1)" ?

Comment: `f` hasn't been (re)defined until after the scope of the func is defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* different variables named `f` in *different scopes* in your code.  First:

```golang
    package main

    var f = func(x int) {}
```

This declares and initialises a function variable `f` in package scope. Then:

```golang
    func Bar() {
        f := func(x int) {
            if x >= 0 {
                println(x)
                f(x - 1)
            }
        }
        f(2)
    }
```

Creates a second, different_ function variable, *also* called `f`, in the scope of the `Bar()` function.

This second `f` variable does not exist until it has been initialised.  To illustrate this, consider this simplified example that demonstrates the problem:

```golang
package main

func main() {
   foo := foo + 1
   println(foo)
}
```

What would you expect this code to do?  Output `1` or fail compilation?  The answer should be obvious.

Even though the declaration of `foo` lexically occurs before the initial value expression, `foo` does not yet exist when *evaluating* that expression.

If a packaged scoped variable called `foo` is introduced, then the `foo` in `main` **can** now be initialised using an expression that references that value:

```golang
package main

var foo = 2

func main() {
   foo := foo + 1
   println(foo)
}
```

Which will now compile just fine and output `3` (the `foo` in `main` is said to `shadow` the `foo` in the package scope).

We can illustrate the same problem in your code by renaming the package scoped function variable `f` to something else, let's say `pf`.  You should then find that your code no longer compiles:

```golang
    package main

    var pf = func(x int) {}

    func Bar() {
        f := func(x int) {
            if x >= 0 {
                println(x)
                f(x - 1)   // << compilation error: `f` does not exist
            }
        }
        f(2)
    }

    func main() {
        Bar()
    }
```

You can see this in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/t6LXm2PLqgw).  The solution is hopefully obvious: change the code of the function assigned to `f` so that it references `pf`:

```golang
    package main

    var pf = func(x int) {}

    func Bar() {
        f := func(x int) {
            if x >= 0 {
                println(x)
                pf(x - 1)   // << compilation error: `f` does not exist
            }
        }
        f(2)
    }

    func main() {
        Bar()
    }
```

It then should be apparent that the function in `f` is not referencing itself.

Key to this is the fact that the function in `f` *has no name*.  `f` is **not** the name of the *function*, merely the name of a *variable* that holds a *reference* to an **anonymous** function.

Further thought and you will realise that an anonymous function is incapable of recursion.